# How to write a good program for blocking unwanted / harmful websites

Tags: c++, windows, network-programming, winsock

I intend to write a simple application that will block network traffic (HTTP and HTTPS) with unwanted / malicious web sites.

Assumptions:

- At the beginning the logic will be simple. After entering in the browser the address from the "black list" my logic should take control under communication and send defined by me site contents
- Later I want to add some logic that will search web body looking for unwanted / harmful words
- The program will be written in C++
- I do not want to use existing libraries (open source etc.) only write all from scratch. J just want to learn windows network mechanism and layers

Unfortunately, I am a layman when it comes to play with the network layer in Windows.

Where do I start?
Where and how should I inject my filtering logic?

Comment: Is this an application or a learning project?  If you want a filter, you'll be much better off using existing libraries, or finding something Open Source and modifying it to fit.  If you want to learn how to do the Windows networking stuff in C++, go ahead.

Comment: I just want to learn a bit...

Answer (score 4):

You should look into [Windows Filtering Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/network/wfp.mspx).  This API gives you access to the network stack at a very low level.

Comment: Is it any chance that it works on XP? I'm afraid no chance...

Answer (score 3):

You have at least 2 options:

- Build your own proxy that filters traffic and replace unwanted content and setup this proxy in browser settings.
- Create NDIS filter driver. You can start reading about NDIS [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff568356%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). You can also find [sample driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff570732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in WDK.

I would prefer the first option.

Comment: I think the second option is much more safe because it goes deeper into layers. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But it also requires low-level manipulating with network packets.

Answer (score 0):

I a working on something similar in my spare time(as if I had any).
It's not very easy.
It depends a lot on the OS version.
There's [LSP(Layered Service Provider)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_Service_Provider) but as I understand it it doesn't work on Win 7 or later. There is an implementation of something similar to what you are trying to achieve [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92512/Writing-a-Parental-Control-Software-for-Windows).
For Win 7 and above there is the filter driver alternative but I tested it and if the site is using SSL you won't see anything. You have to somehow handle this either within the driver itself or redirect the traffic to a man-in-the-middle proxy. I didn't get that far yet.
Anyway [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Windows-Filtering-Platform-7b0a3d91) is M$'s official sample. And you might also be interested in [this](http://www.komodia.com/wiki/index.php?title=Komodia%27s_Redirector).